Can't remove pagination from SwiperJS component
I am building a slider using SwiperJS in React and I want to remove the pagination. However, when I set the pagination to {false} the component does not load anymore and the following error is displayed in the console:
TypeError: Cannot create property 'clickable' on boolean 'false'
at 0:9921:37
at Array.forEach ()
at Ee (0:9910:15)
at Pe.initialize (0:10109:11)
at Pe.connectedCallback (0:10147:12)
at appendChildToContainer (react-dom_client.js?v=077d055f:8447:24)
at insertOrAppendPlacementNodeIntoContainer (react-dom_client.js?v=077d055f:17434:15)
at insertOrAppendPlacementNodeIntoContainer (react-dom_client.js?v=077d055f:17441:15)
at insertOrAppendPlacementNodeIntoContainer (react-dom_client.js?v=077d055f:17444:17)
at insertOrAppendPlacementNodeIntoContainer (react-dom_client.js?v=077d055f:17441:15)
JSX Code
<swiper-container className="mySwiper" pagination="false" pagination-clickable="false" slides-per-view="2.5"
          space-between="20" free-mode="true"
          >
            {images.map((image) => (
              <>
                <swiper-slide>
                  <img src={image.url} key={image.id} />
                </swiper-slide>
              </>
            ))}
        </swiper-container>

CSS Code
swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

swiper-slide img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

Script added in index.html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>

I tried to remove it using CSS using the code below however it did not work.
.swiper-pagination {
    display: none !important;
}


A solution I found is changing the opacity of the pagination active and inactive bullets in the root using CSS.
:root{
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-opacity: 0;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity: 0;
}

